# Retrieve commits after pushing to a different source

Tags: git

During the course of a project, I somehow changed source of my `origin` remote to a completely different repo. Consequently, I pushed some commits there.

Now, I'd like to retrieve those and transfer the commits to the remote with correct url.

I'm thinking to copy `origin` to a new remote, change the url, pull the changes from teammembers, and cherry-pick commits from the newly copied (that now has a correct url).

Comment: Do you need to retrieve the commits? If you pushed those commits, they exist in your local repository. "*I'm thinking to copy origin to a new remote*" does the new remote not exist? We need more detail about the state of the remotes and your local.

Comment: Yes, I want to retrieve the commits and push them to a correct repo without overriding my teammates' effort. 
Several commits are now seen in a new repository. When I do `git remote -v` it shows origin git@bitbucket.org:other/repo.
Now I want to change origin url to git@bitbucket.org:project/repo but fear that if I just change the url, that I will lose changes of the last days which I've been pushing to other/repo.

Comment: So I figured out changing the src url doesn't revert or remove anything and just changing the remote url back is safe. After that I just push the chanages after pruning unnecessary branches. I'll turn the comment into an answer tomorrow.

Comment: *Every* Git repository contains *every commit* (that it's ever gotten its little grubby paws on). There's one exception to this rule: if you forcibly eject a commit from a Git repository, it *may eventually* go away. But in general Git is greedy for commits. You can't get rid of them. This is why commits spread, virus-like, once made. Your Git has Git-sex with another Git and now they both have it.

Comment: Keep in mind you can have multiple remotes.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the source after comitting changes to a different remote url won't delete the any progress you've made. This means that you can just commit the progress to a new url.